# Change datatype of RDD[Array[Any]] in order to convert RDD to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataset of weather measurements (obtained from [here](http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/))

I aim at creating a RDD from this dataset and then convert it to a dataframe.

For simplicity, I parse what I need from the dataset (so that I won't have to load the whole huge dataset each time) using the following parse function:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def parse(rawData: RDD[String]): RDD[Array[Any]] = {

    rawData
      .filter(line => line.substring(87, 92) != "+9999") // filter out missing temperature labels
      .map { line =>
      val year = line.substring(15, 19).toInt
      val month = line.substring(19, 21).toInt
      val day = line.substring(21, 23).toInt
      val hour = line.substring(23, 25).toInt
      val latitude = line.substring(28, 34).toDouble / 1000
      val longitude = line.substring(34, 41).toDouble / 1000
      val elevationDimension = line.substring(46, 51).toInt
      val directionAngle = line.substring(60, 63).toInt
      val speedRate = line.substring(65, 69).toDouble / 10
      val ceilingHeightDimension = line.substring(70, 75).toInt
      val distanceDimension = line.substring(78, 84).toInt
      val dewPointTemperature = line.substring(93, 98).toDouble / 10
      val airTemperature = line.substring(87, 92).toDouble / 10

      Array(year, month, day, hour, latitude, longitude, elevationDimension, directionAngle, speedRate, ceilingHeightDimension, distanceDimension, dewPointTemperature, airTemperature)
    }
  }
```

Then I parse my dataset using the parse function:

````
val rawNOAA = sc.textFile("./NOAA-065900/065900*")
val parsedNOAA = parse(rawNOAA) ```
````

Now I need to convert the `parsedNOAA` rdd into a dataframe. However, since it follows the type of `RDD[Array[Any]]` , I cannot use the following syntax:

```
import spark.implicits._
parsedNOAA.toDF()
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Any]]
```

The first two elements of the rdd are as follows:

```
parsedNOAA.take(2)
res12: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(1949, 1, 1, 6, 49.617, 6.2, 380, 180, 15.4, 240, 9000, 1.1, 2.2), Array(1949, 1, 1, 12, 49.617, 6.2, 380, 180, 15.4, 450, 20000, -1.1, 5.0))
```

Therefore, `parsedNOAA`  contains only Double or Int. I need a method to change from Any to something understandable for Spark so that it will be able to convert my rdd to dataframe.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Why don’t you just use a case class instead of Array[Any]?

Comment: Any is always a bad starting position...